# Using another html.tpl.php for specific page

Tags: theming

I have googled this alot but none of the suggestions I found works for me.

I want to use another html.tpl.php template for a specific page, preferably matched with the url-string to that page, but the id works aswell.

This is the code I'm trying now (in template.php):

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

    $nid = arg(1);

    if ($nid == '1715') {
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__test';
        echo "testing testing";
    }
}
```

My custom template file is named: html--test.tpl.php.

The echo part does print on the page so the $nid is correct.

mytheme is not the actual name of my theme, but I replaced it here.

Comment: Your parameter is `$variables` but you're assigning to `$vars`...

Comment: Be careful when you copy code, make sure the parameters match the code :)

Answer (score 7):

Note, there's already template suggestions for `html.tpl.php` generated by [`template_preprocess_html`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) (see last lines in the function there)

For a specific node page, you can use `html--node--1715.tpl.php` where `1715` is the target node id.